# I need to insert the date and time of employee stamp in and out into mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I need to get employee clockin and clockout, so i have a mysql table called emp_log. The employee clicks the a button and the datatime is automatically inserted into the emp_log table, also the user_id and clock_id.

This should be done without leaving the page and the employee does not have to type in anything. I here is an image about how far I have come. The employee has signed in and now need to click-in button and then sign out.

**Home.php**

```
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT users.*, employees.* FROM users  NATURAL JOIN employees WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico">

    <title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- debug and js -->
    <script src="../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- CSS FOR MY CALENDAR -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link href="//arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="kalenda.css" rel="stylesheet">  

    <!-- SCRIPTS FOR MY CALENDAR -->
    <script class="cssdesk" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script class="cssdesk" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script class="cssdesk" src="netd-bostpdn.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script class="cssdesk" src="//arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


 </head>

 <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header clearfix">
            <nav>
              <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="logout.php?logout">Log Out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <h2 class="text-muted">Hi, <?php echo $userRow['last_name'];?>&nbsp; | Employee No: <?php echo $userRow['emp_no'];?></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Please time stamp</h2>
            <div class="container">
                <div id='calendar'></div>
            </div>          
        </div>
            <br>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <center>
                    <p>
                        <form>
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="Clock In" id="my-button">
                        </form>
                    </p>    
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script>
            $(function() {
              var date = new Date();
              var d = date.getDate();
              var m = date.getMonth();
              var y = date.getFullYear();

              $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                  left: 'prev,next today',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: true
              });
            });

            $('#my-button').click(function() {
                var moment = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
                var dateObj = new Date(moment) /* Or empty, for today */
                dateIntNTZ = dateObj.getTime() - dateObj.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
                dateObjNTZ = new Date(dateIntNTZ);
                var nd = dateObjNTZ.toISOString().slice(0, 19);

                $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'clockin.php',
                    data: { inDate: nd.replace('T', ' ')},
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);  
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        alert("Error."); 
                    }
                });
            })
        </script>
    </div>
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**clockin.php**

```
        session_start();

/* connect to DB */
include_once 'dbconnect.php';


    $indate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inDate']);
    $intime = date('H:i:s');

    $clock_id = NULL;
    $clock_in = $indate." ".$intime;
    $timestamp_in = $indate." ".$intime;
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user'];
    $res2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `employees`.`emp_log` (`clock_id`, `clock_in`, `timestamp_in`, `user_id`) VALUES ($clock_id, '$clock_in', '$timestamp_in', '$user_id')");

    if($res2)
        echo "User in time entry successfully made.";
    else
        echo "Error inserting entry data";
```

Comment: what have you done so far to do this? post your code

Comment: @MickeyUlasi - edit your question and include it there. It's unreadable as comments.

Comment: Hi Suyog and Andrewsi, can you pls help. Thank you

Comment: Should the ajax code be in the clockin.php

Comment: no, it should be in home.php

Comment: Now, I am getting error inserting data

Comment: @MickeyUlasi specify entire error. Paste here full line of error you are getting

Comment: That is just what is printed on the alert

Comment: Its this message if($res2)
        echo "User in time entry successfully made.";
    else
        echo "Error inserting entry data";

Comment: plz again update your post with your code for clockin.php page

Comment: I am using it and i have updated them as well

Comment: if this is the case then why script is still there in your clockin.php file? why haven't you used `mysql_error()` as like I have used?

Comment: Please check it now I have updated it

Comment: still clockin.php file code is different.. check my answer properly and update it

Comment: It now says there is error in mysql syntax

Comment: Now, it say there is error in mysql syntax near 'clock_in', which it shows the time as well

Comment: on clockin.php. just above the line `$res2 = mysql_query(..` write the line as `echo "INSERT INTO employees.emp_log (clock_id, clock_in, timestamp_in, user_id) VALUES ($clock_id, '$clock_in', '$timestamp_in', '$user_id')"` and tell me what it shows in alert?

Comment: Hi Suyog, It works now. Many thanks for the help and contributions. I am very delighted and grateful to you all. Thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot Suyog. You guys are the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery fullCalendar comes with a function [getDate()](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/getDate/) that returns a [Moment](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/) for the current date of the calendar.

For not refreshing the page, you need to use AJAX. Try below code

**home.php** should contain following code

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT users.*, employees.* FROM users  NATURAL JOIN employees WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico">

    <title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- debug and js -->
    <script src="../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- CSS FOR MY CALENDAR -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link href="//arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="kalenda.css" rel="stylesheet">  

    <!-- SCRIPTS FOR MY CALENDAR -->
    <script class="cssdesk" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script class="cssdesk" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script class="cssdesk" src="netd-bostpdn.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script class="cssdesk" src="//arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


 </head>

 <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header clearfix">
            <nav>
              <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="logout.php?logout">Log Out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <h2 class="text-muted">Hi, <?php echo $userRow['last_name'];?>&nbsp; | Employee No: <?php echo $userRow['emp_no'];?></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Please time stamp</h2>
            <div class="container">
                <div id='calendar'></div>
            </div>          
        </div>
            <br>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <center>
                    <p>
                        <form>
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="Clock In" id="my-button">
                        </form>                             
                    </p>    
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script>
            $(function() {
              var date = new Date();
              var d = date.getDate();
              var m = date.getMonth();
              var y = date.getFullYear();

              $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                  left: 'prev,next today',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: true
              });
            });

            // add button click code here
            $('#my-button').click(function() {
                var moment = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
                var dateObj = new Date(moment) /* Or empty, for today */
                dateIntNTZ = dateObj.getTime() - dateObj.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
                dateObjNTZ = new Date(dateIntNTZ);
                var nd = dateObjNTZ.toISOString().slice(0, 19);

                 $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'clockin.php',
                    data: { inDate: nd.replace('T', ' ')},
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);  
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        alert("Error."); 
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**clockin.php** page should contain following code

```
    session_start();

    /* connect to DB */
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if(isset($_POST['inDate']))
    {
        $indate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inDate']);

        $clock_id = NULL;
        $clock_in = $indate;
        $timestamp_in = $indate;
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user'];
        $res2 = mysql_query("INSER INTO emp_log (`clock_id`, `clock_in`, `timestamp_in`, `user_id`) 
        VALUES($clock_id, '$clock-in', '$timestamp-in', '$user_id')");

        if($res2)
            echo "User in time entry successfully made.";
        else
            echo "Error inserting entry data: ".mysql_error();
    }
    else
        echo "No date received.";
```

Your **HTML** snippet for Clock In button should look like:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="Clock In" id="my-button">
</form>
```

**IMP NOTE:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. STOP USING THEM. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

**EDIT:**

From `fullcalendar` we get selected date in following format format(in `var moment`)

> Tue Nov 24 2015 12:47:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

So we will convert it in desired format as follows:

```
var dateObj = new Date(moment) /* Or empty, for today */
dateIntNTZ = dateObj.getTime() - dateObj.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
dateObjNTZ = new Date(dateIntNTZ);
var nd = dateObjNTZ.toISOString().slice(0, 19);
```

Now, `nd.replace('T', ' ')` will give us date time like

> 2015-11-24 12:50:51

So in clockin.php, you can directly use the variable `$_POST['inDate']`.

See the updated code.

This how it looks now in the hompe.php

```
$('#my-button').click(function() {
                var moment = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
                var dateObj = new Date(moment) /* Or empty, for today */
                dateIntNTZ = dateObj.getTime() - dateObj.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
                dateObjNTZ = new Date(dateIntNTZ);
                var nd = dateObjNTZ.toISOString().slice(0, 19);

                 $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'clickin.php',
                    data: { inDate: nd.replace('T', ' ')},
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);  
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        alert("Error."); 
                    }
                });
            })
```

The clockin.php looks like this now

```
<?php
session_start();

/* connect to DB */
include_once 'dbconnect.php';


    $indate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inDate']);
    $intime = date('H:i:s');

    $clock_id = NULL;
    $clock_in = $indate." ".$intime;
    $timestamp_in = $indate." ".$intime;
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user'];
    $res2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO emp_log (`clock_id`, `clock-in`, `timestamp-in`, `user_id`) VALUES ($clock_id, '$clock-in', '$timestamp-in', '$user_id')");

    if($res2)
        echo "User in time entry successfully made.";
    else
        echo "Error inserting entry data";
?>
```

Comment: are you able to get values on clockin.php page? check `console` for JQuery errors if any and also let me know the `POST` value for `inDate`

Comment: @MickeyUlasi check `console` for `click button not working`

Comment: @MickeyUlasi see the updated code.. its working for me

Comment: Hi Suyog, I get error from the alert

Comment: means it is alerting as "Error." ?

Comment: Yes, but nothing has been inserted into the database table

Comment: error callback will be executed when the response from the server is not going to be what you were expecting.

Comment: what shall i do to solve the problem?

Comment: you need to study basics of PHP, basics of MySQL, basics of JQuery-AJAX and how to use JQuery-AJAX with PHP

Comment: I have tried but I dont understand what am doing wrong here

Comment: @MickeyUlasi can you please update the code in your post?? what ever you have updated since this post has been here from last 5 hours

Comment: @MickeyUlasi check the code for home.php and clockin.php files and make the changes in your code. I have updated the answer

Comment: your button click should be on home.php and NOT ON clockin.php

Comment: I dont understand, when i but my button is in home.php

Comment: @MickeyUlasi have you checked my updated code? for home.php and clockin.php ?